# How to open terminal in idea?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have clicked somewhere and I lose the `Terminal`
[image]

My footer looks like this.
I don't see ways to open Terminal.

please help.

P.S.

Terminal doesn't exist in `view->toolbar`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It should be in `View | Tool Windows`.

Or try to find it though `Search Everywhere` (double <kbd>Shift</kbd>) after that button for `Terminal` will appear on `Sidebar` again.

Answer (score 6):

I just had the same problem in IntelliJ Ultimate 2017.2.3, but `Terminal` wasn't in `View | Tool Windows` either.

I have discovered that `Terminal` was a plugin that I had disabled.